# How long will opencv_traincascade take to complete training?

Tags: opencv

These are the arguments I passed in command line:

```
opencv_traincascade -data car_data -vec cars.vec -bg neg.txt -numPos 8792 -numNeg 8968 -numStages 15 -numHitRate 0.995 -w 64 -h 64 -precalcValBufSize 5120 -precalcIdxBufSize 5120 -numThreads 8
```

and it listed:

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: car_data
vecFileName: cars.vec
bgFileName: neg.txt
numPos: 8792
numNeg: 8968
numStages: 15
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 5120
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 5120
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 64
sampleHeight: 64
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC
Number of unique features given windowSize [64,64] : 8103936
```

looks like it ignored numThreads. After an hour I am still in this block

```
===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   8792 : 8792
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    8968 : 1
Precalculation time: 117.973
```

Memory usage is 11.5 GB and CPU usage is around 14%.

What is this `Precalculation time`?
Why it ignores `numThreads`?
How long will it take to complete the job?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm trying to do the training with opencv_traincascade, but I can not keep going. You could tell me where to find an example on how to use opencv_traincascade? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LorenzoBenassi I've forgotten the keywords I used on google to get that example but you can find a lot on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it ignores `numThreads` because you don't have built OpenCV with TBB support enabled.

In a post on the OpenCV website, I Remember to have read that opencv_traincascade application can use TBB for multi-threading, but to use it in multicore mode OpenCV must be built with TBB support enabled.